# Flat array to a hierarchical multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an flat array that looks like this exemple :

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '1',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[nomenclature exemple]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '0',
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '3',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[droit]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '1',
        ),
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '13',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[législation]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '2',
        ),
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '14',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[statuts]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '3',
        ),
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '15',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[projets de loi]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '4',
        ),
      ),
      5 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '16',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[réglementations]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '2',
        ),
      ),
      6 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '17',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[instruments statutaires]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '3',
        ),
      ),
      7 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '2',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[économie]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '1',
        ),
      ),
      8 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '8',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[analyse cout-avantage]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '2',
        ),
      ),
      9 => 
      array (
        'TreePad_Fields' => 
        array (
          '@ID' => '6',
          '@NAME' => '[CDATA[analyse socio-économique]]',
          '@LEVEL' => '2',
        ),
      ),
    )
```

and I would like to have like this :

```
 $data = array(
    '[CDATA[nomenclature exemple]]' => array(
      '[CDATA[droit]]' => array(
        '[CDATA[législation]]' => array(
          '[CDATA[statuts]]' => array(
            '[CDATA[projets de loi]]'
          ),
        ),
        '[CDATA[réglementations]]' => array(
          '[CDATA[instruments statutaires]]'
        ),
      ),
      '[CDATA[économie]]' => array(
        '[CDATA[analyse cout-avantage]]',
        '[CDATA[analyse socio-économique]]',

      ),
    )
  );
```

I can't figure out how to do it. I've found other examples here for converting flattened arrays into multidimensional ones but not where there's a custom child like this.

Comment: hi  thx for your comment but   still can't figure out how to do it, could you please make it for me !!  it well be so nice of you  ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should say it is a bit inconsistent to want to have the leaves in the datastructure have the `[CDATA...]` name as *value* of an indexed array, while in the rest of the tree they are *keys*.

So, I would suggest to make those leaves also *keyed* by the `[CDATA...]` name, but just with an empty array as value. That way the structure is consistent throughout.

For that structure you could use this function:

```
function buildTree($data) {
    foreach($data as $i => $row) {
        $arr = $row['TreePad_Fields'];
        $level = $arr['@LEVEL'];
        $key = $arr['@NAME'];
        $levels[$level][$key] = [];
        $levels[$level+1] = &$levels[$level][$key];
    }
    return $levels[0];
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$result = buildTree($data);
```

For the sample data given, the result would be:

```
array (
  '[CDATA[nomenclature exemple]]' => array (
    '[CDATA[droit]]' => array (
      '[CDATA[législation]]' => array (
        '[CDATA[statuts]]' => array (
          '[CDATA[projets de loi]]' => array (),
        ),
      ),
      '[CDATA[réglementations]]' => array (
        '[CDATA[instruments statutaires]]' => array (),
      ),
    ),
    '[CDATA[économie]]' => array (
      '[CDATA[analyse cout-avantage]]' => array (),
      '[CDATA[analyse socio-économique]]' => array (),
    ),
  ),
)
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/626547)

Comment: thank you a lot @trincot  :D  you are so good  :D this is exactly what i need